# Ionic Meteor Authentication

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a sample app using Ionic + Meteor, following this link: http://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/ionic/bootstrapping

Everything looked great, but when I came to Authentication I'm stuck.
I know I've to use $meteor.loginWithPassword( for User Account Authentication, but I dont have accounts-password .... how do I install that using the Ionic CLI into Ionic project?

> Object {loginWithPassword: undefined, requireUser: undefined,
>   requireValidUser: undefined, waitForUser: undefined, createUser:
>   undefined…} 
>   TypeError: $meteor.loginWithPassword is not a function
>   ionic.bundle.js:21157

Thanks.

Comment: try `meteor add accounts-password`

Comment: If it is meteor app I can do it, but I'm talking about the ionic app, and it does not allow to add 'accounts-password'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`bower install accounts-password-client-side`](https://libraries.io/bower/accounts-password-client-side)

And include:

```
<script src="bower_components/accounts-base-client-side/dist/accounts-base-client-side.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/accounts-password-client-side/dist/accounts-password-client-side.bundle.min.js"></script>
```